# Print largest/smallest no (even, odd) from user defined list of given size

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

After reviews of my previous codes <sup>[1st](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177374/print-initial-letter-of-an-entered-name), [2nd](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177453/print-total-number-of-vowel-and-consonant-in-an-entered-sentence)</sup> learned many new things. So with those in mind, this is my solution for another question.

> Question: Write a program that ask user for list size and values and find largest and smallest no, even no, odd no?
>
> Expected output: For user defined list,
>
> 1. `[13, 7, 19, 21, 3, 4, 27, 47, 50, 11] -> 50, 3, 50, 4, 47, 3`
> 2. `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10] -> 10, 2, 10, 2, None, None`
> 3. `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9] -> 9, 1, None, None, 9, 1`
>
> Format: `largest_no, smallest_no, largest_even, smallest_even, largest_odd, smallest_odd`

My solution:

```
def largest_and_smallest(given_list):
    """Extracts required numbers from given_list.

    >>> largest_and_smallest([13, 7, 19, 21, 3, 4, 27, 47, 50, 11])
    (50, 3, 50, 4, 47, 3)

    >>> largest_and_smallest([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
    (10, 2, 10, 2, None, None)

    >>> largest_and_smallest([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
    (9, 1, None, None, 9, 1)

    """
    sorted_list = sorted(given_list)
    largest_no = max(sorted_list)
    smallest_no = min(sorted_list)

    list_of_even = [even_no for even_no in sorted_list if ((even_no % 2) == 0)]
    if len(list_of_even) == 0:
        largest_even = None
        smallest_even = None
    else:
        largest_even = max(list_of_even)
        smallest_even = min(list_of_even)

    list_of_odd = [odd_no for odd_no in sorted_list if ((odd_no % 2) != 0)]
    if len(list_of_odd) == 0:
        largest_odd = None
        smallest_odd = None
    else:
        largest_odd = max(list_of_odd)
        smallest_odd = min(list_of_odd)

    return largest_no, smallest_no, largest_even, smallest_even, largest_odd, smallest_odd


def input_handler():
    """Checks validity of input. Any mistakes causes the program to stops."""
    size = input("Enter a size of list?\n>")
    if size.strip() == "":
        exit("Program Terminated. (No Input)")
    elif size.isdigit():
        list_size = int(size)
        list_of_no = [int(input("Enter value:")) for _ in range(list_size)]  # bad input causes error.
        return list_size, list_of_no
    else:
        exit("Program Terminated. (Bad Input)")


def main():
    print("All input should be integers.")
    list_size, list_of_no = input_handler()
    l_no, s_no, l_even, s_even, l_odd, s_odd = largest_and_smallest(list_of_no)
    print()
    print(f"From provided values of list of a size {list_size}:")
    print(f"Largest no.: {l_no}, Smallest no.: {s_no}, Largest even no.: {l_even}, "
          f"Smallest even no.: {s_even}, Largest odd no.: {l_odd}, Smallest odd no.: {s_odd}")
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(main())
```

So, from this review I would like to know:

1. I have used list comprehension as per suggestion in previous code, have I used that correctly? For example, I made separate list for even and odd numbers could I have done that in different way?
2. I made a separate function to handle input is that a bad practice? What is the best way to handle inputs, that checks different corner cases?

If there is any recommendations going forward from this will help me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think overall your code looks really good. There are a few changes I would make to improve readability and such.

---

You use `no` for "number" throughout. This may be fine in your context, but in general in English code it's more common to use `num` to mean number. This would be a simple refactoring to just rename variables and such.

---

When I use Python 3.x I like to take advantage of [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) so my IDE will tell me if I'm using a function/method incorrectly.

For example, using your code:

```
from typing import List, Tuple

def largest_and_smallest(given_list: List) -> Tuple:
    # code here
```

This tells your coding tools that your function should expect a `List` and return a `Tuple`. I find it makes it easier to keep code organized and to read it, and a lot of IDEs will give a warning if you use the function incorrectly.

---

You can check for an empty list with `not` instead of checking its length is zero. For example, this:

> ```
> if len(list_of_even) == 0:
>     largest_even = None
>     smallest_even = None
> ```

Can be shortened to this:

```
if not list_of_even:
    largest_even = smallest_even = None
```

Also combining the assignments to the variables.

You can also use the same technique for empty string, e.g.:

> ```
> if size.strip() == "":
> ```

Can be written as:

```
if not size.strip():
```

---

I find the documentation for your primary function a bit unclear:

> ```
> """Extracts required numbers from given_list.
> ```

I would recommend something more akin to:

```
"""Extracts the following numbers from given_list and returns a tuple containing them:
largest_num, smallest_num, largest_even, smallest_even, largest_odd, smallest_odd
Examples:
# your examples following
```

---

To address your questions:

1. Yes, I think you have used list comprehensions well. Personally I may have extracted `if ((even_no % 2) == 0)` (and `not` it for odd numbers) to a separate function `is_even(num: int) -> bool` to avoid repetition. Those parentheses also are not needed, `if even_no % 2 == 0` will work fine.
2. Having a separate function to handle inputs is good practice, it makes the code simpler to understand, and you could write tests for input to handle corner cases, for example with [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) library, which I use myself and really like.

Comment: Thanks ++ for this through analysis, haven't learned unittest so will do that and for other suggestion will surely follow those in future.

Answer (score 4):

- Your variables are long, without needing to be.
- You don't have to define `largest_even`, amongst others, it'd be simpler to just return the tuple.
- If you're targeting 3.4+, and I don't see why you wouldn't, you can use the default keyword. "[New in version 3.4: The default keyword-only argument.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)"

Leaving you simply with:

```
def largest_and_smallest(numbers):
    even = [n for n in numbers if (n % 2) == 0]
    odd  = [n for n in numbers if (n % 2) != 0]
    return (
        max(numbers, default=None),
        min(numbers, default=None),
        max(even, default=None),
        min(even, default=None),
        max(odd, default=None),
        min(odd, default=None)
    )
```

If you don't like the verbosity of `max`, you could use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to set `default` twice.

```
from functools import partial

def largest_and_smallest(numbers):
    min_ = partial(min, default=None)
    max_ = partial(max, default=None)
    even = [n for n in numbers if (n % 2) == 0]
    odd  = [n for n in numbers if (n % 2) != 0]
    return (
        max_(numbers),
        min_(numbers),
        max_(even),
        min_(even),
        max_(odd),
        min_(odd)
    )
```